# Xamarin com Web Services - Lentidão e Timeout

Tags: xamarin

Desenvolvi uma aplicação com Xamarin usando web services e está me preocupando o fato da comunicação por 3G não estar funcionando legal, tem dado muito timeout e esse erro "Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure".

O que ocorre é que aplicações como Facebook e Instagran que usam uma quantidade significativa de banda funcionam perfeitamente nas mesmas condições.

Será que o caminho é alterar a forma de trafegar os dados, mandando via JSON simples, penso que o problema pode ser pelo fato de Web services trafegarem muitas informações.

Tenho um servidor (cloud) na Amazon em SP e está tranquilo em relação a processamento e memória, o que significa que o problema é da conexão. Via wi-fi, funciona perfeitamente.

Na app eu envio e recebo dados (textos) e imagens, mas o problema tem ocorrido com textos, que é mais leve.

Se alguém já passou por essa situação e puder me ajudar, ficaria grato.

Answer (score 3):

Tudo indica que você está trafegando muitos dados numa mesma requisição.

Se você não pode diminuir a quantidade de dados, tem que aumentar a quantidade de requisições e distribuir os dados entre elas.

Answer (score 0):

Fracionar os dados seria uma das soluções.
Json também é uma boa solução, mas cuidado, lembre-se disto o Json as vezes pode está consumindo mais banda do que aparentemente é visível, exemplo:

```
{
  "data": "xpto",
  "hasMoreData": 1
}
```

No exemplo acima pode parecer até um caso banal por que os dados que você utilizará você "parseará" e pronto, mas se você analisar direito o segundo objeto "hasMoreData" sua descrição em "string" está consumindo mas banda que o próprio valor do objeto que é um inteiro "1";